# How to one to many relationship in a join table in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, mapping, one-to-many

here are mapping files :

### **BusinessCard.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.hibernate.BusinessCard" table="BUSINESSCARD">
        <id length="4" name="id" type="int">
            <column length="4" name="ID"/>
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column length="50" name="NAME"/>
        </property>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="description" type="java.lang.String">
            <column length="250" name="DESCRIPTION"/>
        </property>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

### **BusinessGup.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.hibernate.BusinessGroup" table="BUSINESSGROUP">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" length="4"/>
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" length="25"/>
        </property>
        <property name="description" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="DESCRIPTION" length="250"/>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

### **BusinessContact.hbm.xml (Join table where I want to do one to many mapping)**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.hibernate.BusinessContact" table="BUSINESSCONTACT">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" length="4"/>
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="businessId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="BUSINESSID" length="4"/>
        </property>
        <property name="groupId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="GROUPID" length="4"/>
        </property>      
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

So, on BUSINESSCONTACT table I am trying to do one-to-many mapping between businesscard and businessgroup. Unfortunately I couldnT do that despite searching solution on the web. Can anyone help me about this issue?

Thx..

Answer (score 2):

Don't search on the web. Read the [reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/) instead.

Here's [the section showing an example of a one-to-many unidirectional association](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#assoc-unidirectional-12m).

Your mapping doesn't make sense. If you want a one-to-many association between BusinessGroup and BusinessCard, then the BusinessGroup class should have a collection of BusinessCards.

There shouldn't be a class BusinessContact, since the BUSINESSCONTACT table is just a join table, and not an entity. Its only use is to hold the association between the other entities, and it's thus completely managed by the association.

Comment: I have a question regarding this. Please help me. I have designed database  in mysql and want to map it to the hibernate hbm.xml file. All the database tables are mapped in hibernate no? How would I map a join table of the database and how to declare foreign key from this way